# Other working fluids in Rankine cycle power plants

Tags: thermodynamics

Why do power plants that use the Rankine cycle use the working fluids:

1. sodium
2. mercury
3. serine
4. benzene
5. potassium

Can such plants use other fluids?

Comment: Do rankine use any of these as *working fluids*? If you show the source for your claim, you likely have the answer why right there.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt many Rankine cycles use any of these as working fluids, if working fluid means the fluid that undergoes the actual phase change etc. Rankine cycle engines want fluids with a convenient boiling point - within the temp. range the machine will operate in, at a managable pressure. Most of the times this is water. [Organic Rankine Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_Rankine_cycle) engines exist, these use fluids with lower boiling point to exploit lower temp. heat sources like industrial waste heat or geothermal sources. The wiki article I linked goes into the choice of the working fluid, with more explanation :

- Isentropic saturation vapor curve
- Low freezing point, high stability temperature
- High heat of vaporisation and density
- Low environmental impact
- Safety
- Good availability and low cost
- Acceptable pressures

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the absolutely overwhelming majority of them do.  The number that use any of the fluids you listed is trivial.  Most use water.

Comment: And even the ones using sodium and potassium mostly use them for heat transfer ... to a water based Rankine cycle.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be utility scale [mercury vapor turbines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_vapour_turbine) for combined cycle electricity generation. According to that wikipedia page, the increase in efficiency of steam turbines made mercury turbines obsolete.